# Fastest Way to Parse Large Body of Text into Pages with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the fastest way to parse a large body of text into page in Rails? I'm working on parsing books into pages and rendering the parsed pages in a JSON. The raw text file does not have anything indicating page number. Therefore, we'll be parsing the page by number of words (about 400 words per page). 
The JSON response might look something like this:

```
{ book :  {[
  {page 1: Some example text....}, 
  {page 2: Some example text....},
  {page 3: Some example text....},
  {page 4: Some example text....},
  {page 5: Some example text....}
  ....
]}}
```

What's the fastest way to do this? Are there any gems or external apis we could use?

Thank you.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ it’s more reliable to parse by a number of letters and then add all subsequent non-spaces. Words might have very different length.

Comment: I hope these are short stories or this will take a very long time and be extremely memory consumptive. Also as of right now your object is invalid ( the Hash under book has no key)

Comment: @MackHalliday why the speed matters? Are you planning to parse the text on demand (for example, to have the page size configurable) upon each API call? If not, just preprocess them in advance and let API to do the dumb job (just sending the prepared pages) ...

Comment: We're parsing txt files from the Gutenberg Project, which has over 30,000 books. We'd like to be able to parse the books on demand.